# WordPress converting ../url to http://../url

Tags: urls

I have a page on WordPress, it's slug is `http://example/wordpress/page`. I also have a second page, and it's slug is `http://example/wordpress/page2`.

I want to a link in the first page that links to the second page. So I tried the following:

- `/page2/` - leads to `http://example.com/page2` ❌
- `/../page2/` - leads to `http://example.com/page2` ❌
- `page2/` - leads to `http://example.com/wordpress/page/page2` ❌
- `../page2/` - leads to `http://example/wordpress/page2` ✔

But problem is WordPress converts `../page2/` to `http://../page2/` which obviously doesn't work.

So what can I do to fix this? I don't want to hardcode the url, as the site could be accessed from `wordpress.example.com` and `example.com/wordpress`

Comment: Hi, i think there might be a problem with your site url and home url options. Check your database and see if both `siteurl` and `home` are set to the same value, under `wp_options` table. Or you can also check from `Settings > General`.

Comment: Hi @Jack, they are the same.

Comment: Have you tried changing your page's slug? using `page` may cause conflict with the WordPress's pagination.

Comment: @Jack these are examples, not the real slugs

Comment: Not an answer but a hint: WP always runs under the assumption that is has a certain URL. Making a WP site accessible from multiple URLs will end you in a world of pain in the long run. The issue you're having now is just the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your page at `http://example/wordpress/page2`, then use the following code to output a link to your page, no matter what your site url is:

`echo site_url('/page2/');`

This appends the `/page2/` to your website's url (which is `http://example/wordpress/` ), which would be :

`http://example/wordpress/page2/`